# Javascript async is not working in layerslider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, performance

I have add the code as show below.

```
function add_async($url) {
  if (FALSE === strpos($url, '.js')) { // not our file
    return $url;
  }
  // Must be a ', not "!
  return "$url' async='async";
}

add_filter('clean_url', 'add_async', 11, 1);
```

when i add this code to increase the performance and it increases the page speed in google insight.But it hides the Layer slider and not showing any error.
Any idea is much appreciated.